# Proxmox and PfSense: Connect VMs to PfSense VM

Tags: networking, pfsense, proxmox

I have installed Proxmox on a server with 4 NICs, 1 being used by Proxmox and 1 for PfSense:
[Network Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR71N.png)

I want to be able to connect my VMs in Proxmox to the PfSense VM so the VMs go through PfSense. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I connected the 2nd Ethernet ports to the 3rd port on the server with an Ethernet cable, made a bridge for the ports, connected the 3rd port (bridge) to pfSense and setup firewall rules on pfSense. Then I could connect all the machines I need to go through pfSense to the other bridge (port 2). I am still looking for an easier way to do this so I don’t have to use another 2 ports.

Answer (score 0):

just select in your other VM te LAN port that is used for LAN on the pfsense

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.